# Encoding to AC3 with GStreamer

Tags: audio, gstreamer

Is there an example for producing an AC3 stream? The only example I keep finding is:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v audiotestsrc ! avenc_ac3
```

However, I get an "internal data flow error" every time, with the following right below it:

```
gstbasesrc.c(2809): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAudioTestSrc:audiotestsrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
```

I have version 1.0.6 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the *bitrate* parameter is optional, but the default value (0) is not valid, at least with an *audiotestsrc* source.

This works:

```
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! audio/x-raw,channels=2 ! avenc_ac3 bitrate=192000 ! filesink location=/tmp/ac3test_20130630-0245
```